# Recommendation about studying calculus.

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I will be first year undergrad in Physics next year. I've studied calculus from stewart so far and finished it until the integral part. Now, I am studying calculus from Apostol, because it starts with integral and my question will be about this. Should I continue with Apostol or study from the books like Adam's, Stewart etc.?

Comment: Continue with Apostol.

Comment: If you are going to study physics, I would advise to prefer less rigorous texts. Extra trouble you would have with apostol would benefit someone who is going to be a mathematician.

Comment: Yes, because I am studying without a class sometimes I cannot proceed and have some difficulties.

Comment: As grdgfgr said Apostol is more rigorous than you really need in physics. Your time would be better spent on more physics centered books(I'm sure you can get a better recommendation for such a calculus book at a physics forum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's good to study calculus rigorously if one wants to go far in physics. The kind of thinking using inequalities that goes into proofs in analysis - such as "this term eventually becomes less than $\varepsilon$ for large $N$" - is of constant use in physics. It provides the firm foundations for when a physics professor waves his hands and says "this term is negligible" - it's what he knows because he's learned math properly, but doesn't necessarily say out loud in talking to lower-level undergraduates.

Apostol's book also gives you a level of technical proficiency in computations that you simply can't get in an average textbook. The theory and technique go hand in hand. Apostol's book is also full of examples of applications to the sciences. It was used as the main calculus textbook at Caltech for many years, including for engineering students.

The main drawback to Apostol is that there is no solution manual, as far as I know. Spivak's book has a complete solution manual. The problem is that Spivak's book is somewhat more theory-centred, including topics of greater interest to mathematicians (such as proving the existence of a continuous, nowhere differentiable function). Overall, you might find the issue of the solution manual more important, however.

You should also realize that in practice, integrals are usually calculated by using derivatives. This connection can obviously only be made in Apostol once he's also studied derivatives, and he does it in Chapter 5. On the other hand, the first two chapters will give you a very good idea of what an integral *is* - much better than Stewart of course, although about ten times more work too.

Comment: I have similar thoughts concerning Apostol. But, in my university there is no calculus class which is treated by using Apostol. It is my personal interest and sometimes lack of instructor leads some problems such as stucking at one page of the book and being not able to proceed.

Comment: If you find Apostol too difficult, you can study from books with a lower level of rigour and difficulty, but which are still more rigorous than the average textbook used today. *A First Course in Calculus* by Lang and *Calculus* by Marsden and Weinstein come to mind. Piskunov's book might be okay too.

Comment: No, I have already proceeded from start to the applications of integral part of the apostol. I wondered that if it is necessary to study from that rigorous book for a physics student.

Comment: thanks for informative comments.